# Google Maps iOS API Error Message

Tags: ios, google-maps

Could someone explain this error message to me? Specifically this line:

Set accountToAuthorizerBlock to be able to send authorized requests.

GoogleMapTest[15977:1049856] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7fcd2a430cd0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcd2a5f5f50 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
2015-06-22 10:35:24.694 GoogleMapTest[15977:1049856] Set accountToAuthorizerBlock to be able to send authorized requests.

I believe the crash happens when I tap the map and try to get places from the coordinates. I'm not sure if all of this code is correct:

```
- (NSString*) getNearestPlace : (CLLocationCoordinate2D) position : (GMSMapView*) thisMap {

    GMSCoordinateBounds* theseBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] init];
    [theseBounds includingCoordinate:position];

    GMSPlacesClient* thisPlacesClient = [[GMSPlacesClient alloc] init];
    [thisPlacesClient autocompleteQuery:@"" bounds:theseBounds filter:nil
                               callback:^(NSArray* arrResults, NSError* error) {

                                   NSLog(@"ok");

                                   if (arrResults.count == 0) {

                                       NSLog(@"no place found");
                                   }

                                   if (arrResults.count > 0) {
                                       NSLog(@"%@", arrResults);
                                   }

                                   if (error) {
                                       NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                                   }

                               }
    ];

    return @"";
}
```

The block never gets hit. I get the coordinates from this delegate method:

```
- (void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    [self.myController getNearestPlace:coordinate:self.myMap];
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code related to this crash?

Comment: In your `autocompleteQuery` method, you did not give any search text, you just put a empty string, you should provide a specific text from user.

Comment: I know, I was hoping that I could just use a coordinate bounds and have it return all the places within...I was hoping the empty string would just return all results.

Comment: Based on [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/autocomplete), the Place Autocomplete Service in the Google Places API for iOS returns place predictions in response to a `text-based` location search query. The request includes a `textual search string` and optional filter criteria. You can use this service to provide autocomplete functionality as the user `types`. If you want to find all places near a coordinate, you can use the nearby web service, here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709367/google-maps-ios-sdk-place-id-on-tap/30714651#30714651).

Comment: I have the same problem with accountToAuthorizerBlock